# How can I differentiate $(ye^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=y^2$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I have following relation to differentiate: $$(ye^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=y^2.$$

However, I got a bit confused: I first simplified: $y^{\frac{1}{x}}e^1=y^2$ and then differentiated, but that doesn't seems to approach the right answer.

Comment: Can you show what in your work appears to not approach the right answer?

Comment: what are proposing to prove?

Comment: @wisher I believe the OP has been clear: s/he is not aiming to prove anything. S/he is trying to use implicit differentiation to obtain $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: The work is simpler if you raise both sides to the $x$ power, getting $ye^x = y^{2x},$ or even simpler $e^x = y^{2x - 1}.$ Note that you can even avoid implicit differentiation by solving for $y,$ such as $e^{\frac{x}{2x-1}} = y.$

Answer (score 2):

If the exponents and chain rule are giving you trouble together, you could take the logarithm of both sides first to eliminate the former---
$$\frac{\log y}{x} + 1 = 2 \log y$$
---and then optionally rearrange:
$$x = (2 x - 1) \log y.$$

Differentiating gives
$$1 = 2 \log y + (2 x - 1)\frac{y'}{y}$$
and rearranging gives an expression for $y'$.

Answer (score 1):

The hard way:

$$(y^{1/x})'e=\frac exy'y^{(1/x)-1}-\ln y\ y^{1/x}\frac e{x^2}=(y^2)'=2yy'.$$

then 
$$y'=\frac{\ln y\ y^{1/x}\frac e{x^2}}{\frac exy^{(1/x)-1}-2y}.$$

Using $y^{1/x}=y^2/e$, this can be simplified to

$$\frac{\ln y\ \frac{y^2}e\frac e{x^2}}{\frac ex\frac{y^2}ey^{-1}-2y}=\frac{\ln y\ \frac{y^2}{x^2}}{\frac yx-2y}=\frac{\ln y\ y}{x(1-2x)}=\frac{(2\ln y-1)y}{1-2x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

you are going to differentiate implicitly, you may as well take the $\ln$ of $y^{1/x}e = y^2$ and get $\dfrac{ln y}{x} + 1 = 2 \ln y $ which can be written as 
$$(2x -1)\ln y = x $$ which difference gives you $$(2x-1) \dfrac{dy}{y} + 2\ln y dx = dx$$ therefore $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y(2 \ln y - 1)}{1 - 2x} $$

Comment: @Travis, thank for spotting more than one typo.

Comment: Cheers, @abel. .